# How do you get information from and api and send that discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord.py

How do you get info from an API the one I want to use is https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/, and when the user asks for a player I take the info from the API and send that? For example, the user says !Steph how do I change the link for Steph Curry's stats and send the info there

Comment: You're asking for a lot of stuff at once. I suggest you go step by step, look for a tutorial/guide about APIs, then learn about Discord.py

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn how the API returns the data, how to fetch the data within discord.py, and how to process/parse the data and wrap them into a nice, presentable form.

Unfortunately, we can't help you if you haven't gotten *any* progress. StackOverflow is more of a troubleshooting place; not a how-to-implement-this-idea-101 place.

Generally, the API will return a JSON response. So, you need to make a http request within the `discord.py` command to the API endpoint, and fetch that JSON response. You can process that data into a python dictionary, then parse the data into a `discord.Message` object.

If you had a hard time understanding any of those, please do your research in the respective area you had trouble with. It may be intimidating at first to take them all in, but it is actually really intuitive and straight forward.

How-to's:
[Python API Tutorial: Getting Started with APIs](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/)
[discord.py Documentations](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)